# Error: 415 Unsupported Media Type Angular/C#

Tags: c#, angular

¿Como puedo hacer para enviar una foto de Angular a una api en c#?

He realizado un pequeño formulario para crear un usuario y he agregado un poco de codigo para cargar la foto

```
<div class="col-2">
      <div class="user-photo">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>Foto del Usuario</mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>
            <div class="photo-container">
              <div class="photo-content" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + userForm.get('photoPath')?.value + ')' }" [ngClass]="{ 'no-photo': !userForm.get('photoPath')?.value }">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="!userForm.get('photoPath')?.value" class="add-photo-icon" (click)="handlePhotoUpload($event)">add_photo_alternate</mat-icon>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-photo">
              <label for="fileInput">
                <input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="handlePhotoUpload($event)">
                <mat-icon>add_photo_alternate</mat-icon><span>Agregar foto</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

tengo un pequeño metodo para manejar la foto

```
handlePhotoUpload(event: Event) {
const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

if (inputElement.files && inputElement.files.length > 0) {
  const file = inputElement.files[0];
  const allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']; 
  const maxSizeInBytes = 5242880; // Tamaño máximo de archivo en bytes (5 MB)

  if (allowedTypes.includes(file.type) && file.size <= maxSizeInBytes) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const imageUrl = reader.result as string;
      this.photoPath = imageUrl; // Actualizar la ruta de la foto
      this.userForm.get('photoPath')?.setValue(imageUrl); 
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    // Asignar el archivo a la variable photoFile en userForm.value
    this.userForm.get('photoPath')?.setValue(file);
  } else {
    this._matSnack.open('El tamaño de la foto supera los 5 MB o el tipo de archivo no es el correcto', 'Cerrar', { duration: 5000 });
  }
}
```

}

y atravez de el boton crear ejecuto el siguiente metodo

```
createUser() {
if (this.userForm.invalid) {
  return;
}

const registerDto: RegisterDto = {
  firstName: this.userForm.value.firstName,
  lastName: this.userForm.value.lastName,
  userName: this.userForm.value.userName,
  email: this.userForm.value.email,
  passwordHash: this.userForm.value.passwordHash,
  confirmPassword: this.userForm.value.passwordHash,
  phone: this.userForm.value.phone,
  roleId: this.userForm.value.roleId,
  updatedAt: this.userForm.value.updatedAt
};

const photo: File | undefined = this.userForm.value.photoPath;

if (photo) {
  this._gestorService.registerUser(registerDto, photo).subscribe(
    (response: RegisterDto) => {

      this._matSnack.open('El usuario se ha creado exitosamente', 'Cerrar', { duration: 5000 });
      this._gestorService.navigateTo("home/usuarios");
    },
    (error) => {
      this._matSnack.open('Ocurrió un problema al crear el usuario', 'Cerrar', { duration: 5000 });
    }
  )
} else {
  this._gestorService.registerUser(registerDto, null).subscribe(
    (response: RegisterDto) => {

      this._matSnack.open('El usuario se ha creado exitosamente', 'Cerrar', { duration: 5000 });
      this._gestorService.navigateTo("home/usuarios");
    },
    (error) => {
      this._matSnack.open('Ocurrió un problema al crear el usuario', 'Cerrar', { duration: 5000 });
    }
  )
}
```

}

en mi servicio que llama a la api tengo lo siguiente

```
registerUser(registerDto: RegisterDto, photo: File | null): Observable<RegisterDto> {
let headers = this.getHeader();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('registerDto', JSON.stringify(registerDto));

if (photo) {
  formData.append('photo', photo);
}

return this._http.post<RegisterDto>(`${this._urlBase}/gestionusuarios/register`, formData, { headers }).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

}

y por ultimo en mi metodo de api tengo lo siguiente para crear el usuario

```
[HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterDto registerDto, [FromForm]IFormFile? photo)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var existingUser = await _context.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == registerDto.UserName);

        if (existingUser != null)
        {
            return BadRequest("El usuario ya se encuentra registrado");
        }

        if (registerDto.RoleId == null)
        {
            registerDto.RoleId = 1; // Mozo level
        }
        else if (registerDto.RoleId != 1 && registerDto.RoleId != 2 && registerDto.RoleId != 3 && registerDto.RoleId != 4)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid role ID");
        }



        var newUser = new User
        {
            FirstName = registerDto.FirstName,
            LastName = registerDto.LastName,
            Username = registerDto.UserName,
            Email = registerDto.Email,
            Phone = registerDto.Phone,
            UserRoleId = (int)registerDto.RoleId,
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        };

        if (photo != null && photo.Length > 0)
        {
            var username = registerDto.UserName;
            newUser.PhotoPath = await SaveUserPhoto(username, photo);

        }
        else
        {
            newUser.PhotoPath = "Sin definir";
        }
        var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();
        newUser.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(newUser, registerDto.PasswordHash);

        _context.Users.Add(newUser);

        var log = new Log
        {
            TableName = "Users",
            RecordId = newUser.Id,
            Operation = "INSERT",
            UserId = newUser.Id,
            ColumnName = "ALL TABLE",
            OldValue = "-",
            NewValue = "ALL FIELD",
            Description = "CREACION DE USUARIO",
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        // Agregar el objeto Log al contexto de base de datos y guardar los cambios.
        _context.Logs.Add(log);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var responseDto = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(newUser);

        return Ok(responseDto);
    }
```

El problema es que obtengo Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type

¿Alguna sugerencia para poder enviar correctamente los archivos a mi metodo?

EDITADO: en this.getHeader() tengo lo siguiente:

```
private getHeader() {
const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);

return header;
```

}

Comment: Intenta usando postman, así determinamos si el problema va con la API o con el front. Saludos.

Comment: El problema al parecer viene de angular por que crear correctamente el usuario a travez de postman ¿Puedes ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
registerUser(registerDto: RegisterDto, photo: File | null): Observable<RegisterDto> {
// let headers = this.getHeader();
// headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('registerDto', JSON.stringify(registerDto));

if (photo) {
  formData.append('photo', photo);
}

return this._http.post<RegisterDto>(`${this._urlBase}/gestionusuarios/register`, formData).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Comment: Lo he intentado pero recibo un error lo siguiente:

status: 415
statusText: "Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: Cuando envio registerDto como unico parametro, puedo crear el usuario, pero cuando lo intento enviar con la foto en el segundo parametro obtengo el error en la llamada a la api

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en `this.getHeader()`

Comment: ya lo he editado, en this.getHeader() envio el token de autenticación

private getHeader() {
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);

    return header;
  }